# Datatable Globle Search Select2 input filed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, jquery-select2

Anyone please share the example code for Datatable Global Search Select2 input filed,
see the image i shared

[see Ui here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUUTC.png)

just share the simple example code, select2 input fields are auto-generated, i tried many way but not able to achieve that logic. any one please share the example code

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you